# CodeChef Buying New Tablet solution

Tags: c

When I ran this code why is it giving me incorrect output? In my system I'm getting the correct output. My output is the same as the one given in the [link](https://www.codechef.com/COOK103B/problems/TABLET) but still they wont accept it.

```
int main()
{

    int t, n, b, i;

    scanf("%d", &t);

    while (t--) {
        scanf("%d %d", &n, &b);
        int area[n];
        int max = 0;
        area[0] = 0;
        int p[n], w[n], h[n];
        int count = 0;

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            scanf("%d %d %d", &w[i], &h[i], &p[i]);
        }

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (p[i] <= b) {
                area[i] = w[i] * h[i];
                if (area[i] > max) {
                    max = area[i];
                    printf("%d\n", max);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            printf("no tablet\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  it is missing the needed `#include` statement(s) for the needed header file(s)

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'. Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) use meaningful variable names.  Variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)  't' 'b' 'n' 'i' are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: regarding: `            if(area[i]>max)
            {
                max = area[i];
                printf("%d\n",max);
                count++;
            }`  this outputs another line each time a larger area screen is found,  It should only print the largest screen within the budget constraints

Comment: NOTE: for code to show properly in the code window(s) it must ALL be indented 4 spaces

Answer (score 1):

You are indexing out of the array bounds with

```
for(i = 1; i<=n; i++)
```

You can index an array length `n` with index `0` to `n-1`. So change both the loops to

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

and remove the useless line

```
area[0] = 0;
```

Also, you should not output the result inside the loop, since if the data entry sequence is different from the example it prints a result more than once. Put that afterwards.

```
if(count == 0)
{
    printf("no tablet\n");
}
else
{
    printf("%d\n",max);
}
```